# How to implement a two-state button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles, fluent

I have a simple button, and I would like it to have the behavior of a "sticky" button, such as it visually has two states (much like a switch). In other words, I would like it to maintain its pressed style even after I release the mouse button, but it would have to be clickable.

Is there a way to easily do it in WPF? I'm using Fluent but I could change it if needed.

```
<Fluent:Button Header="myButton" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}" SizeDefinition="Small">
    <Fluent:Button.Icon>
       <Grid Width="16" Height="16">
           <Image Source="../Images/16x16/icon.png"/>
       </Grid>
    </Fluent:Button.Icon>
</Fluent:Button>
```

Something like this:

1- [image: not-pressed]
2- [image: pressed]

PS:

I'm using MVVM, and in the `Command`, I'm checking and changing a `bool` flag to know what state the button currently is. I would be able to bind it to a button property, if it helps in any way.

Comment: `ToggleButton`?

Comment: You should take a look at [`ToggleButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton(v=vs.110).aspx) - it basically does what you're looking for, although it also has a third "_indeterminate_" (`null`) state.

Comment: I came back to answer my own (now silly) question, but you guys were faster! I just found this ToggleButton in other answers, though when I looked it one hour ago, I haven't found it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out there is a component `ToggleButton` that does exactly what I was looking for. Silly me for not knowing it existed in the first place.